# Two quite different meanings of “bear”

Tags: etymology, homographs

As a noun, a *bear* is a type of carnivore. As a verb, to *bear* means to support or produce.

I wonder how the two meanings finally ended up in one single word. Is there any connection between the two meanings which I don’t know yet?

Comment: I think the right question to ask is,"why do these two *different* words have the same spelling?"

Comment: @Jim The OED has seven completely different nouns all spelled “bear”, some of which are used attributively to modify other nouns. It also two completely different verbs both spelled “bear”.  So there are 7+2, not 1+1.

Answer (score 4):

TLDR: Probably not, but maybe.  Both words seem to derive from two **different** PIE roots that we’ve reconstructed to the same spelling (**b<sup>h</sup>er*), so it is no surprise therefore that they should continue to be spelled the same way. See [etymonline](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=bear&searchmode=none) for more.

---

- For the ursid, Old English used [***bera***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bera#Old_English), cognate to Old (and modern) Norse *björn*, and which both drew from older roots relating to the color brown, one of the creature’s most common colors.
- For the verb you’re referring to, Old English used the strong verb [***beran***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/beran#Old_English).  It had the same senses as the Modern English verb *bear*.

Those two are already so close that there is every reason for the two of them to wind up being spelled the same way in Modern English, where it remains a strong verb: *bear, bore, borne*.

And that is probably the end of the story.

However, there might be one other trace. We already know that a conjectured Proto-Indo-European root **bʰer‑* for the verb must also be behind the cognate Latin verb [*fero* (from infinitive *ferre*)](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fero#Latin).   So the Latin verb *fero* and Old English verb *beran* do share a common ancestor. The Latin verb meant several things, but amongst these were the senses of its Old English cognate.

There is some speculation, however, that there is also a connection between the Old English noun *bera* and the Latin adjective [*ferus*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ferus) meaning “wild”, now spelled *fiero* in Italian and Spanish.  The OED cites an author Fick as equating these, in that the bear was ***the*** wild beast (the *bestia fiera*) of the north.

However, such a connection between *bera* and *fera* is questionable and remains to be demonstrated.  That’s because the proposed PIE root for *ferus* “wild” is now [**ǵʰwēr‑*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Proto-Indo-European/%C7%B5%CA%B0wer-) instead, not **bʰer‑* as before with the verb.  It is possible that the wild aspect reinforced the brown one, but I for one am not convinced, as I do not believe that Latin *ferus* for wild and Latin *fero*  for “I bear” have been shown to be related.